# Are Ordered Tests Available in Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I created a test project while following along with a PluralSight video.

After I created my Unit tests, I followed the video instructions:

1. Right Click the Test project
2. Choose Add...
3. The video has options for Ordered Test

I do not have the option for `Ordered Test`.

***Is there something else I need to install, or is this not available in the Express Edition?***

I've yet to find any good information comparing Visual Studio 2013 Express vs Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's not available in the **Express Edition**. 
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704.aspx.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I ended up naming my tests so they execute in the order I want, since it seems to execute alphabetically.

Comment: What do you use for run tests?

Comment: BTW, run tests in an ordered sequence is bad practice. Each test should be independent from others.

Comment: This was just a demo in a PluralSight video the guy was using to show unit testing.  I haven't started using it yet, just trying to learn about it.